# Parse and validate "key1:value1; key2:value2" string to Go struct efficiently?

Tags: go

I have a "key1:value1; key2:value2" like string (string with `key:value` pattern concated by `;`).

Now I wish to parse this string to a Go struct:

```
type CustomStruct struct {
   KeyName1 string `name:"key1" somevalidation:"xxx"`
   KeyName2 int    `name:"key2" somevalidation:"yyy"`
}
```

In the above example, the struct tag defines the name of the key in the string and can provide some validation for its corresponding value (it can set a default value if validation fails). For instance, `KeyName2` is an `int` value, so I wish the `somevalidation` can check whether the `KeyName2` satisfy, let's say, greater than 30 and less equal than 100.

And in another senario, I can define another struct `CustomStruct2` for string like `key3:value3; key4:value4;`

How can I archive this kind of requirement efficiently and elegantly?

Comment: @ThunderCat I don't know whether it is a well-known format or not. What I have with the string is: string with `key:value` pattern concatenate by `;`. Basically the string can be considered as a map[string]string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that you can parse the data to a map[string]interface{}.

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to set the fields.  Here's the basic function:

```
// set sets fields in struct pointed to by pv to values in data.
func set(pv interface{}, data map[string]interface{}) {
    // pv is assumed to be pointer to a struct
    s := reflect.ValueOf(pv).Elem()

    // Loop through fields
    t := s.Type()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {

        // Set field if there's a data value for the field.
        f := t.Field(i)
        if d, ok := data[f.Tag.Get("name")]; ok {
            s.Field(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(d))
        }
    }
}
```

This code assumes that the  values in the data map are assignable to the corresponding field in the struct and that the first argument is a pointer to a struct.  The code will panic if these assumptions are not true.  You can protect against this by checking types and assignability using the reflect package.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/9-dzMbd44Fv)

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess this is my first time to use go reflect